# Props is undefined, but I can see it console logging the prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new-ish to react, and I am trying to load more information into an array of records, only if the user starts scrolling down. The issue is that the new information appears in the array, but if you try to call it, it returns `undefined`. What am I not understanding here?

**The Parent Component:**

```
class ComplementSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      complements: '',
      updatingComplements: false
    }
    this.updateComplementsArray = this.updateComplementsArray.bind(this)
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    let complements = this.props.user.complements
    let groupComplements = this.props.user.groupComplements
    let allComplements = [...complements, ...groupComplements]
    allComplements.sort(function compare(a, b) {
      dateA = new Date(a.created_at)
      dateB = new Date(b.created_at)
      return dateB - dateA
    })
    this.setState({
      complements: allComplements
    })
  }

  updateComplementsArray() {
    this.state.complements.map((complement, index) => {
      let complements = this.state.complements
      if(complement.meeting_id) {
        meetingApiHelper.getMeeting(this.props.currentUser.authToken, complement.meeting_id)
        .then(results => {
          complements[index].meeting = results.data.data;
          this.setState({complements: complements});
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.response)
        })
      }
    })
    this.setState({
      updatingComplements: true
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.props.scrolling === true && this.state.updatingComplements === false) {
      this.updateComplementsArray()
    }
  }



  render() {
    if(this.props.scrolling === true && this.state.updatingComplements === true){
      return(
        <View>
            <Text style={profileStyles.yellowLobsterHeader}>Complements</Text>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.complements}
              renderItem={({item}) => <ComplementItem key={item.id}  item={item} navigation={this.props.navigation}  />}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            />
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
}

export default ComplementSection
```

**The Child Component:**

```
class ComplementItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.item)
    console.log(this.props.item.meeting)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={formStyles.formStandard}>
          <Text style={profileStyles.profileBio}>Placeholder text</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default ComplementItem;
```

In the `componentDidMount` function, `this.props.item` returns:

```
{created_at:"2017-11-08T22:11:27.272Z"
id:29
meeting:{id: 219, requestor_id: 441, requestee_id: 32, lang_one_id: 1, lang_two_id: 6, …}
meeting_id:219
notes:"Clex Sss was really nice and very easy to talk to. I look forward to meeting again!"
reviewee:32
reviewer:441
updated_at:"2017-11-08T22:11:27.272Z"}
```

but `this.props.item.meeting` returns `undefined`

What am I missing here??

Comment: Can you add the stringified JSON response here for the `item` ? The above doesn't look like a correct JSON.

Comment: The above is exactly what it's console.logging. Why doesn't it look correct?

Comment: Do the json keys need quotes? {"id": "219", "requestor_id": "441", "requestee_id": "32", "lang_one_id": "1", "lang_two_id": "6", …}

Comment: The `,` is missing after each key value pair

Comment: Hmm, you might be on to something. Stringified: `{"id":22,"reviewer":441,"reviewee":32,"meeting_id":158,"notes":"Chelsey was really nice, and very easy to talk to. I look forward to meeting again! Excellent speaker!","created_at":"2017-05-18T20:23:59.605Z","updated_at":"2017-05-18T20:23:59.605Z"}`

Comment: So in this response `meeting` key is missing, hence undefined

Comment: 2 questions - why is it showing up when it's not stringified? How can I call meeting (in other words - what am i doing wrong in re-setting the state after the api call)?

Comment: Try one thing replace your code with `let complements = [...this.state.complements]` in the parent component

Comment: This gives me the error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180377/discussion-between-pritish-vaidya-and-gwalshington).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here

### First

You shouldn't mutate the state

```
let complements = this.state.complements
complements[index].meeting = results.data.data; //... Here, you should either use a spread to shallow compare or use tradition JS fix JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(your_obj)) for a deep clone
```

### Second

You need not update `state` on **each map iteration once the api fetch succeeds** which may cause of performance issue.

Therefore you can make use of the `async/await` in this case

```
updateComplementsArray = async () => {
    const updatedCompliments = await Promise.all(
      this.state.complements.map(async (complement, index) => {
        if(complement.meeting_id) {
          try {
            const meetingResults = await meetingApiHelper.getMeeting(this.props.currentUser.authToken, complement.meeting_id)
            complement.meeting = meetingResults.data.data;
          } catch(ex) {
            // handle the api exception here
          }
        }
        return complement // Map expects a return for each iteration. Return the updated complement object here
      })
    )
    // Once the Promises inside map finish executing, update the state
    this.setState({ complements: updatedCompliments });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is an excellent answer, and well explained.